# Play framework not recognizing errors?

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-2.2

I am trying to catch validation errors when submitting a POST request via an HTML form. I have the following code in my `Application.java` class:

```
public class Application extends Controller
{
    ..

    public static Result addSubscriber()
    {
        Form<Subscriber> subscriberForm = Form.form(Subscriber.class);
        subscriberForm.bindFromRequest();
        Logger.warn(subscriberForm.toString());
        if (!(subscriberForm.hasErrors() || subscriberForm.hasGlobalErrors()))
        {
            Logger.error("dammit");
        }
        else // never reaches here
        ...
    }
}
```

And in my `Subscriber.java` class:

```
@Entity
public class Subscriber extends Model
{
    @Id
    public String email;

    @CreatedTimestamp
    Timestamp createdAt;

    ...

    public List<ValidationError> validate()
    {
        List<ValidationError> errors = new ArrayList<ValidationError>();

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+$");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(email);
        if (!m.find())
        {
            Logger.error("\"" + email + "\" appears to be an invalid email.");
            errors.add(new ValidationError("email", "\"" + email + "\" appears to be an invalid email."));
        }

        if (Subscriber.exists(email))
        {
            Logger.error("\"" + email + "\" is already subscribed!");
            errors.add(new ValidationError("subscribed", "\"" + email + "\" is already subscribed!"));
        }

        Logger.warn("whoa!!!!!! " + errors.toString());

        //return errors.isEmpty() ? null : errors;
        return errors;
    }
}
```

The result when I try entering an invalid email:

```
[error] application - "wofutn@nufwu" appears to be an invalid email.
[warn] application - whoa!!!!!! [ValidationError(email,"wofutn@nufwu" appears to be an invalid email.,[])]
[warn] application - Form(of=class models.Subscriber, data={}, value=None, errors={})
[error] application - dammit
```

Why is the error list empty?! As far as I can tell [I am following directions](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaForms). I can't seem to trigger errors no matter what.

I am using Play 2.2.2 so [this appears to be the relevant source code file](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.2.x/framework/src/play-java/src/main/java/play/data/Form.java). I don't immediately see what I'm doing wrong though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **bindFromRequest()** method doesn't mutate an object but returns a new instance of a form. In other words your errors are not assigned to anything because you work on object before validation is applyed. Simply change it as follows to fix the issue.

```
Form<Subscriber> subscriberForm = Form.form(Subscriber.class);
subscriberForm  = subscriberForm.bindFromRequest();
```